# Unable to run WPF application in other computer

Tags: wpf, testing, deployment

I have WPF application, Which works fine on my PC. As this application is going to be used by clients i was trying to run that in few other computers.

**But when i try to run it, it opens window for brief moment and closes itself.**

Looks like .net is just refusing to start the application.

There is nothing on event log. Also my application has error handling at load level so application does not crash if there is an error. so i am pretty sure it's not calling any application code.

What could be wrong in here?

Notes:

-- Application do not have signed assembly as it's in development only. 
-- I am trying to run application by just copying compiled files. No clickonce installation.
-- Tried clickonce installation as well but same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include references, looks like your using references that the target machine doesn't have.

To include references in your project using ClickOnce publishing, go to Publish page, and click on 'Application Files'. There you can see a list of references that your application uses. You can change the publish status to Include, for all the references that the target machine does/might not have.

Comment: I was missing sync framework, which can't be installed using copying dlls. But thanks your answer is most relevant

Answer (score 1):

Is .Net 3.5 installed on all the test computers?  I believe that is the minimum version for WPF support.

Comment: Yes, i verified it has it installed

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this, try running the app as 'Administrator' on the other computer. 
If this works, could be to do with File access issues as I found. 
In my case the oauth token file that I was dynamically creating was being saved with an absolute file path on the development computer. Changing to a relative path worked. 
Of course, there may be other reasons for the app working as 'Administrator' and not otherwise.